# An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'TEST_ENGINE.db'

Tags: c#

I have created an object but despite that I am getting the above error.

```
#if (TEST_ENGINE)

      class TEST_ENGINE
      {
            //creating an instance of all the classes required
            private DBEngine<int, DBElement<int, string>> foo = new DBEngine<int, DBElement<int, string>>();

            public static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                foo.insert()
```

I'm getting an error at `foo.insert()`. What might be the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Main` method is static, which means you don't have to have an instance of the `TEST_ENGINE` class to call `foo` on. But you *do* need an instance to access that `foo` variable.

You could either make `foo` static:

```
private static DBEngine<int, DBElement<int, string>> foo =
    new DBEngine<int, DBElement<int, string>>();
```

Or you could instantiate your class inside the `Main` method:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var te = new TEST_ENGINE();
    TE.foo.insert();
```

Comment: You are right, it did stop working. I used the second option of instantiating the class inside Main.

Answer (score 2):

set DBEngine to static

```
private static DBEngine<int, DBElement<int, string>> foo = new DBEngine<int, DBElement<int, string>>();
```

or declare it in main method

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DBEngine<int, DBElement<int, string>> foo = new DBEngine<int, DBElement<int, string>>();
            foo.insert();
```

Comment: `or declare it in main mathod` what's `Mathod` fix your typo should be `Method`